# WPF - set focus on textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my `WPF` application I have many text boxes on one page.  I want to set focus on the first text box.  I've Googled it and tried different solutions.

XAML Code :

```
<StackPanel Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <TextBlock x:Name="CustNamelbl" Text="C U S T O M E R  N A M E"
               Style="{StaticResource LightBoldTxtblkStyle }"/>
    <Grid Height="35">
         <TextBox x:Name="CustName" Style="{StaticResource Txtbox}"
                  LostFocus="CustName_LostFocus_1"   TabIndex="1"
                  CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="CustName_PreviewExecuted"
                  ContextMenu="{x:Null}" PreviewTextInput="CustName_PreviewTextInput"
                  Margin="0,0,0,0" GotFocus="CustName_GotFocus"/>
         <Rectangle Fill="White" Height="2" Opacity="0.2" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Rectangle>
   </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

C# Code :

```
CustName.Focus();
Keyboard.Focus(CustName);
```

Using this code I am getting `Focus` on that `TextBox`.  I'm also able to open system keyboard. However, I am not able to type anything in that `TextBox`.  Also, that focused cursor is not a blinking cursor, but just a steady cursor.

Comment: Try set focus on loaded event handler. My guess is that you setting focus in constructor. For more details read this: [WPF Input Focus Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I think the issue lies within `CustName_GotFocus`. Try deleting that method from `xaml` for now and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Give your `TextBox` a name and then you can call in your Window-Tag

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=YOURTBNAME}"
```

Comment: Very nice pure xaml, didn't know we could do it this way.